# Howto stream webcam data to a server?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm looking for a way to stream the webcam data from a browser to a webserver. The webcam data is acquired by using `getUserMedia`. One common option seems to be to use a canvas and a timer in order to send screenshots to a server, but I want a proper video stream. WEBRTC seems to be another option, but that might be a bit over the top, plus there is not too much software that runs on a server (i.e. non-browser), speaks WEBRTC, and has bindings for Python.

Maybe I'm missing sompling simpler. For example, could the video stream be streamed using Websockets?

```
'use strict';


var errorCallback = function(e) {
    console.log('Rejected!', e);
};

var successCallback = function(stream) {
    console.log('Got Video.');
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    // ???
    // Stream data to server  
    video.play();

};

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia;


var hdConstraints = {
    video: {
        mandatory: {
            minWidth: 1280,
            minHeight: 720,
        }
    },
    audio: false,
};

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(hdConstraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
}
else {
    console.log('No getUserMedia available.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the current best solution is indeed to use a canvas, create an image from the webcam in regular intervals and send it via websockets.